# converting 'describe' into 'create table' in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, create-table

Can we get a 'create table' command from description (describe )?
I have a table whose description I can get from "DESC TableName". I wish to know if I can get how that table was created (so that I can use the same command for something else)?. I can get sql-dump but I want to know if there is another way. Thanks in advance !

Comment: 'how the table was created'--will you explain a bit

Comment: I meant the actual command which created that table. Thanks to @Sashi, I got it now. It's 'Show create table tableName'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this :::

```
Show create table tableName
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking to make a new *empty* table with the same structure and attributes, you can use:

```
CREATE TABLE newTable LIKE tableName
```

[create table reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom. Actually, I wanted to know if I can get that SQL command which created that particular table.

Comment: No problem, I've added an explanation of what my answer does instead.

Comment: It certainly is helpful. I was not aware of this command too. Thanks for letting me know about it.

Answer (score 1):

Also :

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name
```

Shows the `CREATE TABLE` statement that creates the named table. To use this statement, you must have some privilege for the table. This statement also works with views.

Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-create-table.html

Comment: Sure Sathish. I got it now. Thanks a lot..!  :)