# How could I improve performance for this mysql database?

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization, database-performance

I have a MySQL database with the following structure :

```
mysql> describe company;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


mysql> describe nameserver;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| companyId | int          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ns        | varchar(250) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


mysql> describe domain;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra             |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| id           | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment    |
| nameserverId | int          | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                   |
| domain       | varchar(250) | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                   |
| tld          | varchar(20)  | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                   |
| createDate   | datetime     | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED |
| updatedAt    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
| status       | tinyint      | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| fileNo       | smallint     | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                   |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

The indexes structure :

```
-- Indexes for table `company`
--
ALTER TABLE `company`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `domain`
--
ALTER TABLE `domain`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `nameserver` (`nameserverId`),
  ADD KEY `domain` (`domain`),
  ADD KEY `tld` (`tld`),
  ADD KEY `fileNo` (`fileNo`);

--
-- Indexes for table `nameserver`
--
ALTER TABLE `nameserver`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `company` (`companyId`),
  ADD KEY `ns` (`ns`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `company`
--
ALTER TABLE `company`
  MODIFY `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `domain`
--
ALTER TABLE `domain`
  MODIFY `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `nameserver`
--
ALTER TABLE `nameserver`
  MODIFY `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `domain`
--
ALTER TABLE `domain`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `nameserver` FOREIGN KEY (`nameserverId`) REFERENCES `nameserver` (`id`);

--
-- Constraints for table `nameserver`
--
ALTER TABLE `nameserver`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `company` FOREIGN KEY (`companyId`) REFERENCES `company` (`id`);
```

The amount of data is as following:

```
domain table about 500 millions records
nameserver table about 2 millions records
```

Running this query take about 4 hours to get me the result :

```
SELECT distinct domain FROM domain 
INNER join nameserver on nameserver.id = domain.nameserverId
 WHERE nameserver.companyId = 2
```

The explain result for above query :

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+-------------------

+------------+---------+-----------------------+------+----------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys     | key        | key_len | ref                   | rows | filtered | Extra                        |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+-------------------+------------+---------+-----------------------+------+----------+------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | nameserver | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,company   | company    | 4       | const                 | 1738 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | domain     | NULL       | ref  | nameserver,domain | nameserver | 4       | tldzone.nameserver.id |  716 |   100.00 | NULL                         |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+-------------------+------------+---------+-----------------------+------+----------+------------------------------+
```

My question is how can I improve the speed of getting query from this database?

It is possible for me to change the DB structure or even replace it with another DBMS.

MySQL is running on a VPS with 8.0 GB RAM and dual core CPU.

Comment: A considerable part of the structure of your database is in de defined indexes (the columns with Key=`MUL`).  The info about the existing indexes is not given, a statement like `SHOW CREATE TABLE nameserver`, might share more info than `DESCRIBE nameserver`.

Comment: Yes, I agree `SHOW CREATE TABLE` shows more information that is helpful for query optimization. Also in these questions, you should include result of `EXPLAIN` for your query.

Comment: @Sadegh-Ghanbari  Waiting for your SHOW CREATE TABLE's and EXPLAIN SELECT sql_no_cache (rest of your query); for meaningful analysis.

Comment: The OP is in UTC +3:30 timezone, so we will probably have to wait until at least tomorrow.

Comment: I have updated the question with existing indexes structure.

Comment: [converting 'describe' into 'create table' in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067852/converting-describe-into-create-table-in-mysql)

Comment: @SadeghGhanbari How long does it take to complete your query now?

Answer (score 0):

```
nameserver:  INDEX(companyId, id)  -- in this order (you have this)
domain:  INDEX(nameserverId, domain)  -- in this order
```

("MUL" does not tell me whether you already have either of these composite indexes.  `SHOW CREATE TABLE` is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.)

Comment: I have updated the question with existing indexes structure and explain for the query.

Comment: @SadeghGhanbari - for better performance, add `INDEX(nameserverId, domain)`

Comment: My query filtering based on companyId how could INDEX(nameserverId, domain) improve the performance ?